# Getting errors while blending 2 image

Tags: iphone, image, blend

I am getting these errors in Output View. I am trying to blend an image over another image and my program is also giving the required output. Just wanted to know why these errors are occuring and how to remove them? My code is written below:
**errors:**

`<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0`
`<Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0`
`<Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0`
`<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0`
`<Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0`
`<Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0`
`<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0`

**code:**

```
(UIImage*) blendImage
{
    CGFloat ox = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat oy = self.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat zoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale;
    CGFloat cx = (ox + self.cropRectangleButton.frame.origin.x -75.0f) *2.0f / zoomScale;
    CGFloat cy = (oy + self.cropRectangleButton.frame.origin.y -85.0f )*2.0f / zoomScale;
    CGFloat cw = 600.0f / zoomScale;
    CGFloat ch = 600.0f / zoomScale;
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(cx, cy, cw, ch);
    UIImage *maskImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"teeth02"];
    [maskImage drawInRect:cropRect];
    [self.photo drawInRect:imageViewFrame];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.photo.size);
    [self.photo drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
    [maskImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(cx, cy)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: where and how?? can you help please? I am new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you call `[maskImage drawInRect:cropRect];` outside graphics context. `drawInRect:` requires *current context* to be set.

Comment: Yes thank you. The problem is solved.
I moved [maskImage drawInRect:cropRect]; and [self.photo drawInRect:imageViewFrame]; in between the lines UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
and the problem now is solved